# Display id using ajax to controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I am new in ci and i want to pass is from view to controller in codeigniter using ajax. if i add dataType : 'json', then my ajax can not work and i want to echo data from controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cart").click(function(){
         var subid=$(this).attr('data-index');
         alert(subid);
         $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Home/add_to_cart',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                subid: subid
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Home/add_to_cart';
                 alert(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 var error=xhr.responseText;
        //       alert(error);
              }

        });
    });
}); 
 </script>
```

Controller
      I want to echo the category id when the ajax can send the request

```
$category_id = $this->input->post('subid');
echo json_encode($category_id);
```

Comment: is there any error in your console ?

Comment: `echo json_encode( array('id' => $category_id) );`

Comment: but in ajax code i  use dataType:'json', the success function can not alert

Comment: because your redirecting before alert . take look to my answer @VidhiPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is all information what Freshers need to handle in CodeIgniter :)

> First remove '`index.php`' from CodeIgniter url via `.htaccess`. Create .htaccess file where CodeIgniter 'index.php' exist.

***.htaccess*** (*Using windows, just rename any blank text file as <kbd>**.htaccess.**</kbd> to create a .htaccess file, So easy ...*)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

***How to enable mode_rewrite in WAMP***
[image]

***How to enable mode_rewrite in WAMP manualy***

*1 - Open apache’s configuration file using your favorite text editor.*

*2 - The configuration file generally locates at:**{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf***

*3 - If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file 
at:**{xampp_dir}/bin/apache/apache-xxx/conf/httpd.conf** or **{wamp_dir}/bin/apache/apache-xxx/conf/httpd.conf***

*4 - Search for the following string:**#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** and uncomment it (remove the ‘#’ sign).*

*5 - Now search for another string **AllowOverride** None and replace it by **AllowOverride All***

*6 - Finally **Save the changes**, close your text editor and **Restart your apache server**.*

***Set 'base_url' automatically***

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dynamic Base Url
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Put below code in 'index.php' on top
|
*/
    define('APP_URL', ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}".str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

***Config Settings***

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = APP_URL;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

***Config CSRF Settings*** (*If you are not passing CSRF token in form, or not using CodeIgniter Form Helper. **Otherwise you will not able to POST param or call Controller Method via ajax or Form POST***)

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

> ***Now, Questions Answer :(***

***JavaScript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // define base url
            var _CI_BASE_URL_ = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
            /**
             * ---------------------------
             * Example -1 with Url Params
             * ---------------------------
             */
            // on click cart button call ajax
            $(".cart").click(function(e){
                // stop default button behaviour
                e.preventDefault();
                // get subid from button attr
                var subid = $(this).data('index');
                // ajax function
                $.ajax(
                {
                    // *Notice: just send 'subid' with ajax url and CodeIgniter will take it from url
                    url: _CI_BASE_URL_ + 'home/add_to_cart/' + subid, 
                    // method
                    type: "POST",
                    // data type
                    dataType:'json',
                    // success callback
                    success: function(data) {
                        // why server response, we already have subid in JavaScript vars
                        // we can user that same to redirect in url
                        window.location.href = _CI_BASE_URL_ + 'home/add_to_cart/' + subid;
                    },
                    // ohh! we got error
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // get ajax error
                        var error = xhr.responseText;
                        alert('Request made some error: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });
            /**
             * ---------------------------
             * Example -2 with POST Params
             * ---------------------------
             */
            // on click cart button call ajax
            $(".cart").click(function(e){
                // stop default button behaviour
                e.preventDefault();
                // get subid from button attr
                var subid = $(this).data('index');
                // ajax function
                $.ajax(
                {
                    // just send subid with url and CodeIgniter will take from url
                    url: _CI_BASE_URL_ + 'home/add_to_cart_another', 
                    // method
                    type: "POST",
                    // POST params
                    data: {subid: subid},
                    // data type
                    dataType:'json',
                    // success callback
                    success: function(data) {
                        // if got the JSON with key cat_id
                        if(data.cat_id){
                            // if you want to alert, first alert then redirect
                            alert('CodeIginter retuned Cat ID: ' + data.cat_id);
                            // redirect user now..
                            window.location.href = _CI_BASE_URL_ + 'home/add_to_cart_another/' + data.cat_id;
                        }else{
                            alert('Category ID not return or null...');
                        }
                    },
                    // ohh! we got error
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // get ajax error
                        var error = xhr.responseText;
                        alert('Request made some error: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

> ***Now CodeIgniter Controller :( :(***

```
<?php
// Security First Matters...
(defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'));

/**
 * Class Home CI Controller
 */
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * Default run method
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    /**
     * [add_to_cart description]
     * @param [type] $cat_id [description]
     */
    public function add_to_cart($cat_id)
    {
        /**
         * Codeigniter is enough smart to take parameters if passed in url
         * if url is 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/home/add_to_cart/100'
         * '100' will be assign to $cat_id by CodeIgniter
         *
         * intval to make sure only integer
         */
        // echo response for ajax call as JSON
        echo json_encode(array('cat_id' => intval($cat_id)));
    }

    /**
     * [add_to_cart description]
     * @param [type] $cat_id [description]
     */
    public function add_to_cart_another()
    {
        /**
         * get cat id from post and sanitize by passing 2nd param as true for XSS Clean,
         * Security always matters...
         *
         * intval to make sure only integer
         */
        $cat_id = $this->input->post('subid', true);
        // echo response for ajax call as JSON
        echo json_encode(array('cat_id' => intval($cat_id)));
    }
}
/* End of file home.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/home.php */
```

***Now, I am going to sleep.. :D Tada!! ....***

Comment: which loation i need to creat this file .htaccess

Comment: You can create in your project root folder where Codeigniter index.php file exists

Comment: in url without index.php page ther error is come page not found so i need to use index.php

Comment: Hello Neeraj Singh when i   dataType:'json',   always my javascript alert error and without json i can't recive my data to controller

Comment: @VidhiPatel, please share your form action url.. make sure if accessible via url.. check ajax response what you are getting by Browser console..

Comment: localhost/PizzaUp/home/add_to_cart this is my form action url in ajax responce console there is no error

Comment: @VidhiPatel did you set htaccess there..? and removed 'index.php' from 'config.php', can you able to access controller method from direct url, is your ajax working properly and you are getting success response, check ajax response from browser console or network tab.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller `echo` with header like this

**php** :

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$category_id));
```

**Ajax** : change your success function code order

```
success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
               temp = JSON.parse(data);
               alert(temp.id);
               //window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Home/add_to_cart';

            },
```

Comment: success function can't be alert

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, In your Controller funtion add_to_cart just do it like this:

```
$category_id = $this->input->post('subid');
echo $category_id;
```

Just dont add json_encode() of it.
Then if you want to return to your ajax request just do it like this

```
success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
},
```

That should be work.

just comment if it is not work.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it your `url:<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Home/add_to_cart` going to the right controller? and also remove your `window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Home/add_to_cart';` so that it will not reload.

Comment: I think you must change your ajax url just like this. `url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/add_to_cart',` if have `index.php` but if you dont have just use ` url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/add_to_cart',`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>.'/Home/add_to_cart',
            data:{'subid':subid},
            success:function(data){
                //location.reload();
            }
        });
```